# Parsing rss feed with simple HTML dom not working for any element

Tags: javascript, php, dom, rss

Im using Simple HTML DOM to screen scrap an rss feed http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/09218009, this is my code:
    require_once DOMAIN_DIR . 'simple_html_dom.php';

```
$articles = array();
getArticles('http://rss.sciencedirect.com/publication/science/09218009');

function getArticles($page) {
    global $articles;

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($page);

    //echo $html;

    $items = $html->find('.entry'); 
    echo sizeof($items);
    /*foreach($items as $post) {
        # remember comments count as nodes
        $articles[] = $post->innertext;
        //echo $html;
    }

    foreach($articles as $item) {
        echo "<div class='item'>";
        echo $item;
        echo "</div>";
    }*/
}
```

The good part is that `load_file($page)` works and when I output it to the browser it displays the whole page.

Good run so far.

Now the problem is that `$items` is equal to [], yes nada!

When I analyze the dom I see that there is a javascript initialization function which I suspect is the culprit.

I need to know how:

1. Can this php library do some sort of js initilization
2. If no, what other alternatives can I use

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "some sort of js initialization" ?

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't have any html or js, it's just xml. Which also doesn't have any style elements so '.entry' doesn't exist. Do you mean to be searching for the "item" tag?

Comment: The javascript part is in the header and goes like `<head>
<title>ScienceDirect Publication: Ecological Economics</title>
<script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://browser/content/feeds/subscribe.js">
Filtered chrome url chrome://browser/content/feeds/subscribe.js
</script>
</head>
<body onload="SubscribeHandler.writeContent();" onunload="SubscribeHandler.uninit();">` WriteContent() is the initialization code?it happens on load. I need to load the page without using a browser

Comment: That JS is what your browser adds so that you can subscribe to it from within your browser. PHP obviously won't see it because it's not using a browser. All it sees is the pure XML feed, which is all the server is actually sending. If you do "view source" instead of using e.g. Firebug, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @rjdown, thank you. I see what you mean and how to solve the issue. Carry on!